# Pass an instance of a button to its onclick function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my program I am changing the onclick behavior of my buttons as:

```
          button.attr('onclick','function1()');
```

I would like to pass function1() an instance of the button as there are a variety of buttons which may from time to time would access this function1() on clicking them and knowing their parents is a must for my logic.

Is this possible?

Comment: Don't do that.  Use `on()`.  See the docs.

Comment: Yeah Ill do that. I know about that I just wrote it here out of habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
button.attr('onclick','function1(this);');
```

You can pass "this" to the function, then that parameter will be the button.

```
function function1(myButton){
//do stuff
}
```

Alternatively, you can use jquery and an anonymous function

```
$(button).click(function()
     {
         var myButton = this; // in this scope "this" is the button.
     });
```

Comment: I cant use the anonymous function I think cause this onclick behaviour changes inside nested functions.
when I am doing myButton.val() or myButton.parent() its not running?

Answer (score 2):

You can always pass the `this` context and use it

```
 button.attr('onclick','function1(this)');
```

But why do you want to attach a inline event to you button. It is a better practice to attach the events directly.

```
button.on('click', someFunction);

function someFunction() {

   this

   // this corresponds to the button that is currently clicked.
}
```